# Pagination Last Button not disabling when no data in datatable

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, datatable, pagination

[I am using DataTable Jquery Pagination, When no data found in datatable, Previous, Next buttons of pagination is disabling by default but not the last button].

```
table = this.$el.DataTable(
        {
            data: this.props.data,
            paging: true,
            oSearch: { "sSearch": param },
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            orderCellsTop: true,
            displayLength: 25,
            processing: true
```

Comment: please provide more explanation, your goal / question, your source code (not in image), and what you have tried so far

Comment: I am using DataTable Jquery Pagination, When no data found in datatable, Previous, Next buttons of pagination is disabling by default but not the last button

Comment: hi, you can use css for disabling the button. but you can hide it, straightforward way: "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        if ($('#el tr').length < 1) {
            $('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
        }
    }

Comment: Yes, It works Thank you, I don't want to hide the button but disable it.